# How does blogger.com know that it's me?

Tags: http, cookies, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

When I sign in with google and go to `blogger.com` (A google property) `blogger.com` knows that it's me.  How does `blogger.com` identify me.  Do I have to have visited it at some point and logged in, or does the browser send an identifier set by google to blogger.com?

Comment: Your 2nd point is valid :).
How? It's better you check that yourself. Open an incognito window, open blogger.com to login (Login screen). Right click on screen -> Inspect Element. Go to 'Network' tab. Check the 'Preserve Log' checkbox. Now, enter your username and password. You can actually see the sequence of requests made by your browser to google's servers and then to blogger's server.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out.  Part of my question is "Is it possible for one domain to create `something` / set `something` in the browser that allows another domain to identify me?  So in other words is it possible for google to set something in the browser that will subsequently identify me to blogger.com?  I don't think this is possible...but standards are evolving fast so I figured I'd double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blogger.com` main page pulls in an `iframe` from `accounts.google.com` where your login session with Google runs

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=blogger&hl=nl&passive=true&go=true&continue=https://www.blogger.com?rinli%3D1
```

and you'll notice that it does so using the `passive=true` flag which means that it won't prompt you if you're not logged in but it will silently return the result of this request to the caller, in this case `blogger.com`.

If you're **not** logged in the HTTP response is:

```
Location: https://www.blogger.com?rinli=1
```

if you are logged in it will be something like:

```
Location: https://accounts.blogger.com/accounts/SetSID?ssdc=1&sidt=<token>&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blogger.com%3Frinli%3D1%26pli%3D1%26auth...
```

where `<token>` represents your user identity in some Google/Blogger specific format.

Comment: FWIW: this is all non-standard stuff that resembles OAuth

Comment: Awesome - thanks - do you know if oauth 2 provides a more standard way of doing this?